How to access the arrival date of the source block as a string?
Im using a source block in Anylogic and I want to use the selected arrival date as a string in another code.

I want to use the "cle" as a string for defining a function. Does anyone know how I can access it?
Many thanks for your help in advance.

Use the "Database query wizard" to get access to any data you want.
Or, if you want to just print the date when it creates a new agent in the source, type traceln(date().toString()) in the Source block's "on arrival" code box.
Or call your function in that code box using myFunction(date().toString()) assuming the function needs a String input and sits on the same agent type as the source

Thanks for your answer. That would be a feasable approach but it does not solve my problem. The reference should be to the Arrival date: field in the Source block because my code in myFunction() should change automatically if a different Arrival date: is selected.

That is not how it is designed to work and also not a useful way of working, imo. Instead, load the same date from the dbase in your function and do some if-else code, if need be (also not elegant but may solve your problem)

bit better: load the date via a separate function and let both the myFunction() and the source feed from the function. Now, you have full control and could even replace the actual date with some custom dates, bypassing the dbase if need be
